# Dataprep string column in format yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS to datetime

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep, trifacta

How do I convert in Dataprep a `string` column with format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` to a `datetime` column?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be automatically recognized but try replacing the space with a dash and see if it changes to date time data type automatically.
[image]